# Three line C# program with Rest API GET call fails with statusCode 403, but succeeds with the same url in Postman

Tags: c#, rest

```
var resp = (new HttpClient()).GetAsync("https://api.chess.com/pub/player/Prodigio7/games/2003/08").Result;
Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode);
Console.ReadKey();
```

I was expecting a successful GET call to the Rest API endpoint with the OK success status code. That Rest API call does not require credentials or authentication of any kind.

Comment: Yes that takes care of it. You simply have to assign the User-Agent header. Thanks @Dijkgraaf

Comment: It was the user @500-InternalServerError you need to thank.  I just edited your question, they proposed the duplicate